# Gyroscope plugin (native) not working in Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins, gyroscope

I am trying to use Gyroscope plugin from Ionic native. Following is my ionic info.

> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
>      ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
>      cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
>      Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
>
> System:
>      Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
>      Node              : v8.9.1
>      npm               : 5.8.0
>      OS                : Windows 10

Following is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
// import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Gyroscope, GyroscopeOrientation, GyroscopeOptions } from '@ionic-native/gyroscope';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  btnLabel_ReadSensors: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    // private platform: Platform,
    private gyroscope: Gyroscope
  ) {
    this.btnLabel_ReadSensors = "Start";
    // platform.ready().then(() => {
    // });
  }

  ReadGyroscope() {
    this.gyroscope.getCurrent({ frequency: 500 }).then((orientation: GyroscopeOrientation) => {
      console.log(orientation.x, orientation.y, orientation.z, orientation.timestamp);
    }).catch((reason) => console.log("Rejected:", reason));
  }

}
```

In above code, ReadGyroscope() is a click callback for a button on UI. In this function, I am trying to read current gyro data and log it on console.

I get following console output whenever I click the button.

> [23:36:28]  console.warn: Native: tried calling Gyroscope.getCurrent, but the Gyroscope plugin is not installed.
>
> [23:36:28]  console.warn:Install the Gyroscope plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-gyroscope'
>
> [23:36:28]  console.log: Rejected:plugin_not_installed

Following is already done:

1. I have already installed the plugin as per [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/gyroscope/).
2. Updated app.module.ts as suggested in documentation.
3. Tried to read data in HomePage constructor with check for
   platform.ready().
4. Tried reading data periodically using watch method.

My issue is similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040696/ionic2-ionic-native-and-cordova-plugin-gyroscope-error) but as it is old, no solution was suggested and the tool versions are changed, I am posting this issue.

I also referred [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/438); but I think the issue was specific to other plugin.

Someone suggested to install gyro plugin directly from git (see [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-native-gyroscope-not-working/127122/8)). Tried that too but no success.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the output of `ionic cordova plugin list`

Comment: This is what I get  > cordova plugin ls  
cordova-plugin-gyroscope 0.1.4 "Device Gyroscope"

Comment: So it appears that the plugin is added. I have tested accelerometer plugin in exactly same manner and it works perfectly.